# zip files, wrong size

Tags: php, pdf, zip

I have a folder containing many PDF files. I have built a script that zip these pdf files into 100mb batches each.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$pathToFiles = "../pdffakturor_test/";
$maxFileSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
$counter = 1;
$currentsize = 0;
$created_at_datum = date("Ymd");
$created_at_clock = date("Hi");
$zip = new ZipArchive;

if($counter <= 10)
{
    $counter = sprintf("%02s", $counter);
}

$zip->open('PROD_SE_C_S_E_'.$created_at_datum.'_'.$created_at_clock.$counter.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($handle = opendir($pathToFiles))
{
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (substr($entry, -4) == ".pdf")
        {
            $filesize = filesize($pathToFiles.$entry);

            if($currentsize >= $maxFileSize)
            {
                $zip->close();
                $zip = null;
                $zip = new ZipArchive;
                $currentsize = 0;

                if($counter <= 10)
                {
                    $counter = sprintf("%02s", $counter);
                }

                $zip->open('PROD_SE_C_S_E_'.$created_at_datum.'_'.$created_at_clock.$counter.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
                $counter++; 
            }
            $zip->addFile($pathToFiles.$entry, $entry);
            $currentsize += $filesize;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

The problem I have is that the first zip batch becomes 183mb and the others 91,6mb. I can't figure out why the first becomes 183mb?

Comment: You look at the sizes of the files you compress, not at the compressed file size. You're not doing what you think you do. Evenso, I cannot see why the first file should be twice as big as the others. The only thing I can think of is: A very large PDF file.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware: There is no extra large PDF file.

Comment: (A) How many files are in the first archive and (B) what are the uncompressed sizes of each?

Comment: @l'L'l: There are ~400files in the first batch. The uncompressed size of each what?

Comment: The size of each file, or, rather what is the largest one.